# How can I print Chinese font in android logcat?

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I change emulator's input language to Chinese it throws an error `Unfortunately(chinese..) has stopped..`  Can anyone please suggest me the how to make it workable with chinese language?
 ![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know I am right or wrong but I have solved this issue with the help of setting environment variable

```
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

I just Answered this because some one who face this same issue could try this solution. May be this help someone....